# Trimming and Compression the image of paperclip using rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I want to trimming the image of paperclip in my database.
Because I`m running my own private web service, but I forgot to add the styles when user create the image...

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :styles => { # I forgot to add this styles
                    :medium => "370x370#", # I forgot to add this styles
                    :thumbs => "120x120#" # I forgot to add this styles
                  }
```

So I want to run the rake task and trimming like 370×370# and 120×120#.
But I cant`t find the way to trimming the image after user save.

Does anyone assist me ?

Answer (score 0):

The paperclip gem comes with a rake task for exactly this purpose:

```
rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails
```

Just run that from the command line and it will take care of generating all of your reduced-size images.